# Diagnostic plots GLM

Tags: r, binary-data, diagnostic

I done a binary regression,it's possible that the the plot of residual vs Predict has two different line? I never see before one like this[image]

Comment: Standrdized residuals don't make sense for logistic regression models.  Instead, you should bin and group your predictors and then analyze deviance residuals.

Comment: So default diagnostic plot are meaningless for binary regression

Comment: Yes.  You have to do a little extra work to get some meaningful diagnostics.  Read up on deviance residuals and deviance diagnostic plots.